# Cannot pass a parameter Javascript to JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, parameter-passing

I'm having some trouble solving this issue. the code that matters is:

```
 for( k=1; tamanho>k ; k++) {

 var a= "#{BDEStats.getListaJobStats().get(k).getName()}";
```

This is javascript and im trying to pass "`k`" to my bean invocation. but JS doesnt recognize "`k`" inside the bean call

Do you know a way I can escape a character so JS recognizes it? or concatenate the bean invocation?

Any ideas??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `#{BDEStats.getListaJobStats().get(k).getName()}` evaluate on server side but `k` is a javascript vaiable which runs in client, so i think its not possible.

Comment: @Karthikeyan is right, your options are either generate the full array of values when the page is generated (of course, values will not be updated) or use ajax/partial rendering of JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using JSON and pasing a JSON Object to Javascript. Further details [Read a Java array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231194/read-a-java-array-in-javascript)